# Taxonomy/Ontology of software bugs?

Tags: taxonomy, ontology

Is there a taxonomy of ontology of software bugs?

Comment: You want a list of different types of bugs and how they relate? Can I suggest a community wiki then?

Comment: @tenpn How do I create a community wiki?

Comment: @tenpn I'm looking for a reference to a blog or article that answers the question (i.e., that has the taxonomy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the beginnings of one on the [Wikipedia page for Software Bugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug#Common_types_of_computer_bugs). It lists them by their cause though. Personally I find that less useful than a system that would list them by their manefestation, because you don't really know the cause until you've debugged it.

Also, that causal approach by defintion leaves off my two favorite bugs, the [Heisenbug](http://foldoc.org/heisenbug) and the [Schrodenbug](http://foldoc.org/schroedinbug).

Answer (score 2):

Many bugs are rather specific to the language.
If you're looking for cross-language errors/mistakes, you may start from [anti-patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Security-wise, a well known taxonomy of software bugs (introduced to a wider audience by Gary McGraw in his series of books on software security) distinguishes between an *implementation bug* and a *design flaw*. An implementation bug is a low-level defect lurking in your implementation. A typical example for an implementation bug is a buffer overflow. A design flaw, on the other hand, is a 'logic' bug within your implementation that allows a malicious person to break or circumvent your system or some security mechanism you implemented simply by using it in a manner you didn't anticipate. A good example for this are flaws in API design which allow an attacker to combine specific calls to the API to force the system to do things that the designers of the system did not anticipate.